# How to detect which UILabel was tapped?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4

I have three UILabels. I want to detect **which label is Tapped, and then retrieve the string value of that label**.
 this is how I am trying, I could only manage to detect tapped position, But I couldn't detect which label was tapped.

Label Creation

```
for (NSInteger i=1; i<=[pdfs count]; i++){
    UILabel *newLabel=[[UILabel alloc] init];
    newLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:[[pdfs objectAtIndex:(i-1)] lastPathComponent]];
    newLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10, 60*i, 320, 20);
    newLabel.tag=i;
    newLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:20.0f];
    newLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    newLabel.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:newLabel];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
    [newLabel addGestureRecognizer:singleTap]; 
    [newLabel release], newLabel=nil;
    [singleTap release];
}
```

Detect Taps

```
 - (void)handleSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
```

{

```
CGPoint location;
location = [recognizer locationInView:self.view];

NSString *documentName;
if(location.y<150.0){
    documentName = [[pdfs objectAtIndex:0] lastPathComponent]; 
}
else{
    documentName = [[pdfs objectAtIndex:1] lastPathComponent]; 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UIGestureRecognizer has a reference to a view it is attached to, so you can get your label's tag from it:

```
int touchedtag = recognizer.view.tag;
documentName = [[pdfs objectAtIndex:touchedtag-1] lastPathComponent];
```

Comment: It was only a matter of time... ;)

Answer (score 5):

As you have add `GestureRecognizer` on label

```
 // called when touch is began or when user touches 
    - (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
    {
          UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject]; 

          UILabel *theLabel = (UILabel *)touch.view;

          if (theLabel.tag == 1)
          {}
          else if ...
    }
```

Comment: thanks ! its helped me to change label text while detect touch

Answer (score 4):

A gesture recognizer knows what view it belongs to.

```
UIView *theView = recognizer.view;
// cast it to UILabel if you are sure it is one
UILabel *theLabel = (UILabel *)theView;
```

Answer (score 3):

Why do you want to use labels as buttons? Just use buttons instead, they can be configured to look just like labels.